# Stall submitting of a form with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have a few ajax requests that need to complete before I can submit a form.

How can I stall within a form.submit() call until all ajax requests are done?

```
var incompleteAjaxCalls = 0

// each ajax call runs incompleteAjaxCalls++ 
// followed by incompleteAjaxCalls-- upon completion

myForm.submit(function () {
    //sleep while incompleteAjaxCalls > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

prevent the form from submitting, then submit when ajax calls have completed

```
myForm.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this;

    $.when(
       $.ajax({url: 'ajax1'}),
       $.ajax({url: 'ajax2'})
    ).always(function() {
        self.submit();
    });

});
```

**EDIT:**

For array you could do

```
myForm.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this,
        xhr  = [];

    xhr.push(
        $.ajax({url: 'ajax1'})
    );

    xhr.push(
        $.ajax({url: 'ajax2'})
    );

    $.when.apply($, xhr).always(function() {
        self.submit();
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that recurse indefinitely?

Comment: @Ramin - Nope, not if calling the native `submit()`, and not the jQuery `submit()`, there's an important difference there as triggering a native submit event with javascript does not trigger the jQuery event handler.

Comment: can you modify that code to be able to pass an array of deferreds instead?

Comment: Thanks. :) Why do you replace the `always` call with a `then` call in the second version? Based on the docs it seems like always will run pass or fail, but you `then` call only has a pass call back.

Comment: No particular reason, you could just as easily do `$.when.apply($, xhr).always(function() { ...`